# поде́лать vs сделать, both mean to make/to do and are perfective

Tags: словоупотребление, значения, выбор-слова

Beginner here.

I'm trying to figure out the difference between [поде́лать](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C#Russian) and [сделать](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C#Russian).

According to the above wiktionary links, they both mean to make / to do and are both perfective verbs.

Are they synonyms?  In their some connotation difference between the two?  How would I know which to use?

Which one is correct (if any...): Я сделал ошибку vs Я поделал ошибку.  I seem to find way more examples of the former on [reverso](http://context.reverso.net/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4/%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/%D1%8F+%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BB+%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83)

Also, they both list the imperfective form as `делать`, so I am confused as to why `делать` needs 2 perfective forms.

Many thanks / большое спасибо

Comment: Try a better dictionary— https://translate.academic.ru/поделать/ru/en/

Comment: @VCH250 Thanks for the link, though it gave more examples, it definitely wasn't as clear about the nuances given in the answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Many Russian verbs have several perfect forms with prefixes `"по-"` and `"с-"`. `"C-"` prefix usually means that the act is complete, while `"по-"` means doing something without having a tangible result. Ex. `"сходить"` - to go (and come back), `"походить"` - to walk for a while.

In case of `"делать"`, predominant perfect form is `"сделать"`. `"Я сделал ошибку"` - "I made a mistake". The word `"поделать"` has a much more narrow use. Ex. `"Он что-то там поделал"` - "He did something there", the implied meaning is that the work was either incomplete or incompetent.

There is, however, one very common phrase with the word `"поделать"` - `"Ничего не поделать"`, meaning "There's nothing can be done". Using the word `"сделать"` in this case will be inappropriate, unless we talk about an event in the past, when a window of opportunity to fix something existed, but now it's gone - `"Ничего уже не сделаешь"` - "Nothing can be done *now*".

P.S. The typical "incomplete, intermittent" meaning of `"по-"` verbs does not hold true when there are no corresponding `"с-"` verbs, or the `"с-"` verb has a distinctly different meaning. In those cases `"по-"` verbs describe successfully completed acts. Ex. `"постирать"` - "to wash" (clothes), `"починить"` - "to fix". There are no respective words like `"сстирать"` or `"счинить"`. Ex.2 `"помыть"` - "to wash" (rigid object) - the word `"смыть"` - "to wash something away" - has a different meaning.

Comment: Ok, it sounds like a pretty subtle point, a perfective verb (so a single, completed action) without a tangible result.

Thank you for an explanation that not only answers my question but why there would be multiple perfect forms.

Comment: **Поделать**  has its own imperfective form **поделывать**

Comment: Значение слова поделывать: - что, делать понемногу, исподволь; делать иногда, порою, временем. Что поделываешь? как живешь, можешь. По зимам столярную работу поделываем, тем кормимся.

Comment: @V.V. true, but only because there is no such word as "сделывать" [Более глубокая информация](https://books.google.com/books?id=KZbSAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA210&lpg=PA210&source=bl&ots=5C_wN0njZY&sig=IWB1rVZyyz9DVqSshbGft7fsNPE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiq9PPJmZLZAhXplVQKHd-zDiA4ChDoAQgmMAA#v=onepage&f=false).

Comment: essentially it is по-- do a bit, some of X, a little bit/ and с-- make, do, create. Just like in English we have --think over, think through, think a bit, think up etc, so does Russian have multiple perfective forms.

Comment: "Постирать" has also a meaning "to wash a little bit for a while". It's doesn't always describe a completed act.

Comment: @Abakan - true, but mostly when talking about rigid objects. Perhaps 99% of the word's use is associated with linens/clothes and a completed act of washing.